# Partial/Streaming Enumeration for Convenience in C#/Linq

Tags: c#, linq, parsing, stream

Sometimes, when dealing with elements in an array, I find it would be valuable to treat an IEnumerable as a read-only stream of the specified type. In instances such as byte- and text-manipulation, .Net has this somewhat covered with the StreamReader and TextReader classes, but their interfaces are not as clean to work with as, for example, Linq.

My initial (And flawed) understanding of IEnumerable was that it somehow kept track of its position in the iterable, rather than starting a new iteration on each usage.

My attempt at its usage while dealing with an IEnumerable which contained sequences of [4 bytes][n bytes] where 'n' was the length specified by the first 4 bytes was similar to this:

```
var len = BitConverter.ToInt32(input.Take(4), 0);
return input.Take(len);
```

This was not correct, in that the "input" enumerable was not modified by calls to Take (As is intended by its design), leaving the first 4 bytes doubly-represented and 4 unread. A call to "Skip" can be used, but evokes multiple enumeration of the source, which is unwanted. ToArray() calls are a patchwork solution to the issue, but can consume inordinate amounts of memory through multiple-storage when dealing with large chunks. I am looking for an alternative method of performing this behavior wherein the enumerable is shifted forward in a similar behavior to a stream.

This behavior is able to be emulated partly with extension methods on Enumerators, but it seems somewhat clunky with its dependence on user-managed- or possibly multiple-disposal depending on implementation. An example:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Take<T>(this IEnumerator<T> enumerator, int count) {
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        if(!enumerator.MoveNext()) {
            using(enumerator) {
                break;
            }
        }
        yield return enumerator.Current;
    }
}
public static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerator<T> enumerator) {
    using(enumerator) {
        while(enumerator.MoveNext()) {
            yield return enumerator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

To summarize, while my question implies the solution may lie in enumeration mechanisms, I am looking for a clean way to act on streams of arbitrary types which can also (cleanly) deal with formats with dimensions dependent upon or declared by previous elements. Being that this is a common task in parsing (Which often doesn't use raw byte- or text-streams, as notable with the request for generics support), for example, I presume there is a relatively succinct way of handling it?

Comment: Could achieve what you want by using a generic Queue https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx which you can construct from an a generic IEnumerable ?

Comment: Side note: sample (pseudo-)code you want to achieve may help...

Comment: @AlexC The generic Queue was a good idea, but it copies the entire enumerable for editing. Commonly, I'm using these sort of behaviors in networking for stream interpretation on the server-side, and that requirement is deal-breaking.